# Detect text and change background color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello my friend i have the code below:

```
<div class='post-inner'>
<span class='item_status'>Sold</span>
<span class='item_status>Offer</span>
</div>
```

and I want to change the background color for every text using javascript.

For example:

Detect **Sold** text using javascript then change the **Red** background color.

and

Detect **Offer** text using javascript then change the **blue** background color.

Thank you before

Comment: already find on google and this site too but i cant find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we're doing here is looping over all elements with class item_status checking the inner text if it contains the word then adding a class based on that

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item_status').forEach(i => {
  i.textContent.indexOf("Sold") !== -1 ?
    i.classList.add('red') :
    i.innerText.indexOf("Offer") !== -1 ?
    i.classList.add('green') :
    null;
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
   
<div class='post-inner'>
<span class='item_status'>Sold</span>
<span class='item_status'>Offer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: do you understand whats happening here i can explain

Comment: yes i know that, only I can not explain using writing. and you have helped me. Thank you very much

Comment: Don't use `.innerText`, that's IE's old non-standard property. Use the standard version, `.textContent` instead. Also, unless you're assigning to (or returning) something on the left-hand side, the ternary operator is not the proper method to use.

Comment: What happens when the word is found not by itself within a `span`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it doesnt throw an error :) you're correct about textContent will change, I think i'd prefer to use a tenary here just because multiple ifs can clutter and i prefer the readability but yeah also valid point and im not returning or assigning with it for it to return i'd still have to add return before the start of the tenary

Comment: I didn't say it would throw an error. What it would do is colorize all the words in the span. See my answer below for the way to accomplish this.

Comment: that's true but it wasn't specified in OPs question but if that was the intention your answer is great :)

Comment: Also, be aware that not all browsers support a `.forEach()` call on the node list returned from `querySelectorAll()`. This is why you should (for the time being) convert that node list into a proper array with: `Array.prototype.slice.call(anything that returns a node list).forEach()` as I do in my answer.

Comment: are you saying if there was only one item it wouldnt return an array? therefore wouldnt loop?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `.forEach()` is an `Array.prototype` method and `.querySelectorAll()` actually returns a "node list", which is an "array-like" object, but not one that actually derives from `Array.prototype` and, in some browsers, attempting to call `.forEach` on a node list will fail with an error like `forEach is not a function`.. So you need to convert the "array-like" object into an actual `Array` instance to be sure that the `.forEach` call won't fail.

Comment: You can read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) but note that the suggested way of converting a node list to an array (`Array.from()`) is going to fail on those same older browsers, so `Array.prototype.slice.call()` is suggested because that code has been around for many years and is supported everywhere.

Comment: thank you I've already upvoted your answer but cheers i use babel but this is very good information to know if building some quick in vanilla

Comment: I don't think Babel would pick this up because we're not really talking about ES6 syntax to be transpiled. It's more of how the user-agent handles the node list API.

Answer (score 2):

Without making modifications to the structure of the HTML up front, you're going to have to read all of the text and then isolate the words to be styled by wrapping them with `<span>` elements and then have CSS styles applied to them.

```js
let elementToBeSearched = document.querySelector(".post-inner");

// Begin traversing the child elements as an array
Array.prototype.slice.call(elementToBeSearched.children).forEach(function(node){
  // Replace keywords with span elements that are tied to the correct CSS class.
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/Sold/g, "<span class='sold'>Sold</span>");
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/Offer/g, "<span class='offer'>Offer</span>");
});
```

```css
.sold { color:red; }
.offer { color:green; }
```

```html
<div class='post-inner'>
  <span class='item_status'>Sold Item</span>
  <span class='item_status'>Offer</span>
  <div>
    This is some other random element that may contain lots of words, including
    the words Sold and Offer.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thats clever nice

Comment: @JoeWarner It doesn't replace the whole `span`, it wraps the individual words in their own `span` element. This way, if there are other words in the same original span, they won't get colorized.

Comment: perfectly what i mean too

Answer (score 0):

Changing color based on the value is not a good option here.

In order to render this string (Sold or Offer), you should know what is the status of the item. This means that you can add a different CSS class, based on what is the status of the item and then apply the colors in the CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item_status");

for(let i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
  if(items[i].innerHTML === "Sold"){
    items[i].style.color = "red";
  }
  else{
    items[i].style.color = "blue";
  }
}
```